# how can i upload a photo when it is taken from the default camera app in flex mobile?

Tags: android, ios, flash-builder, dropbox, flex-mobile

I know how to take a picture and upload it with flex mobile, but i have seen that the Dropbox app automatically uploads the photo that you take using the default camera app.

can this be made in flex mobile or how does Dropbox do it?

Answer (score 1):

Maybe you can do it by using the [Camera ANE by distriqt](http://distriqt.com/native-extensions#camera)

You get the picture as [BitmapData](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/display/BitmapData.html) and then upload it by using [URLRequest or URLStream](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/as3/dev/WS5b3ccc516d4fbf351e63e3d118666ade46-7ee2.html).

Also you can try [FileReference](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/net/FileReference.html) for uploading.

Comment: but you have to enter the app that you made and then take a picture? or can you use the default camera app and detect it and upload the picture that they took?

Comment: You'll probably need to run a background process to do this if you want it to run while your application doesn't have focus. You can look into background execution in AIR see if that does it for you otherwise you'll have to look into native code (most likely an ANE).